# Is there any public SQL Server with sample databases

Tags: sql-server

I study the SQL Server technologies, and want to try connect to remote server.

Did anybody knows a public server with sample databases for testing?
The Google didn't help me, at the moment.

Comment: A public server for testing sql! how should it react if some one run a query to drop the database? or delete all rows from a table? what happens to the others? Of course there is a sample database named Northwind which you can download and attach it in your instance and do what ever you want.

Comment: Did you check virtual labs.

Comment: @VahidND You can create users and set permissions, so you can avoid these kinds of situations.

Comment: @VahidND, the first link in google for MYSQL public server leads here: http://www.ensembl.org/info/data/mysql.html. I can, at least, connect to the server... might be other options.

Comment: @ Upvote MarkAnswer, as I see virtual labs lessons are based on local server.

Comment: I believe GoDaddy has a cheap plan which can include a SQL Server Express installation. Grab a copy of the public Northwind databases, instal that on your instance, and you'd be set to go.

Comment: @SchmitzIT - it is good when user have computer with windows. But what if not - there no where to install the SQL Server.

Comment: @Kaa - I don't think SQL Server works on anything other than Windows.

Comment: @SchmitzIT - of course. Exactly in this situation can help public, maybe read-only, server. Nothing else.

Comment: You can sign up for a free year of Amazon RDS which will allow you to launch an instance of SQL Server http://aws.amazon.com/rds/

Comment: I think for some our and maybe your needs [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6) can be a choice ;).

Comment: This one allows remote connections https://docs.rfam.org/en/latest/database.html

Answer (score 9):

[SQLFiddle.com](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6)

- If you want help with a *tricky query*, and you'd like to post a question.
- If you need to *build a representative database* (schema and data) and post a link to it in your question.
- If you want *(a) unique URL(s)* for each database (and each query) will be generated as you use the site.
- If you want to *compare and contrast* SQL statements in different database back-ends.
- If you *do not have a particular database platform* readily available, but you would like to see what a given query would look like in that environment.

Answer (score 2):

A view solutions from [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_any_free_SQL_database_server_online):

- https://www.freemysqlhosting.net/
- https://cloud.google.com/sql/
- https://www.freesqldatabase.com/
- https://free.caspio.com/
- https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql